# Create a penetration testing app on android

Tags: android, testing, penetration-testing

I am planning to create a penetration testing app. The app will list all the installed apps on the android device and once the use selects an app the analysis of the selected app must be done on the android phone itslef.

Is there any framework or tool that allows me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I just write it app that it similar to yours not long ago. But what kind of analysis you want ? Class PackageManger can get All the Application installed on your phone.

```
    public abstract List<ApplicationInfo>  getInstalledApplications(int flags)
```

you can get the application's ApplicationInfo like size ,name,icon and so on .

Comment: I would like to check if the app is vulnerable. Check if access the network without user consent. Check if the data is being passed over a unsecure connetion..I want to check these kind of basic vulnerabilities. I can get the list of app installed but how can I perform these checks?

Comment: okay. I don't think that can work.  I just know you can read one application's Manifest Infomation to check it's uses-permission or check something like that.

Comment: There are tools online that generated a report when I give an apk. So they are doing it somehow. How can I do the same in an app? If you have any idea regarding that please share it

Comment: Could you please tell me the Name of the Application that you say ? I want to have a look

Comment: I am looking for something similar to Google Play Protect

Comment: I found what I am looking for. It is an API by google called SafetNet API.